# public api com.android.internal.r Android numberpicker

Tags: android, launcher

hi there i am making a launcher
all works out great
but i want to add some options to the launcher and i need a numberpicker
so i took the source of trebuchet as example

but this gives me 1 error 
i cant import com.android.internal.R
com.android.r is private but i dont know a public api to fix it
hope someone can help me out this is the code

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference {
   private int mMin, mMax, mDefault;

    private String mMaxExternalKey, mMinExternalKey;

    private NumberPicker mNumberPicker;

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray dialogType = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.DialogPreference, 0, 0);
        TypedArray numberPickerType = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference, 0, 0);

       mMaxExternalKey =      numberPickerType.getString(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_maxExternal);
        mMinExternalKey =   numberPickerType.getString(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_minExternal);

        mMax = numberPickerType.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_max, 5);
        mMin = numberPickerType.getInt(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_min, 0);

        mDefault =  dialogType.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Preference_defaultValue, mMin);

        dialogType.recycle();
        numberPickerType.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        int max = mMax;
        int min = mMin;

        // External values
        if (mMaxExternalKey != null) {
            max = getSharedPreferences().getInt(mMaxExternalKey, mMax);
        }
        if (mMinExternalKey != null) {
            min = getSharedPreferences().getInt(mMinExternalKey, mMin);
         }

         LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater)     getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker_dialog, null);

       mNumberPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);

       // Initialize state
       mNumberPicker.setMaxValue(max);
       mNumberPicker.setMinValue(min);
       mNumberPicker.setValue(getPersistedInt(mDefault));
       mNumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    // No keyboard popup
        EditText textInput = (EditText)   NumberPicker.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.numberpicker_input);
        textInput.setCursorVisible(false);
        textInput.setFocusable(false);
        textInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

         return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            persistInt(mNumberPicker.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android");
```

You cannot access id's of com.android.internal.R at compile time, but you can access the internal resources at runtime and get the resource by name. 
You should be aware that this is slower than direct access and there is no guarantee, that an internal resource will be available in future versions of android.